# Architecture of Liferay Project?

Tags: architecture, jakarta-ee, portal

What is the main difference between Event Driven Architecture and Model Driven Architecture?  Is there any real work use cases available?

Comment: The question is slightly vague - can you give a bit more information on what it is you're trying to architect.  Generally it is simpler to use single sign-on and use Liferay as a "Portal" to other integrated systems.

Answer (score 4):

The material for this is scattered across. However please see the following links.

1. [Logical Architecture](http://www.liferay.com/community/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Logical+Architecture)
2. [Advanced Liferay Architecture Whitepaper](http://discover.liferay.com/tech-admin-whitepapers/advanced_liferay_architecture) (This requires you to
       sign in to liferay)
3. [Liferay EE Reference Architecture and Hardware Requirements](http://www.liferay.com/documents/14/5fc9c6bb-2c25-4080-986e-4000c572a603)

Answer (score 0):

You can find Liferay portal architecture design here:
http://www.liferay.com/web/guest/community/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Liferay%204.x.x%20Portal%20Architecture